# cannot access object of class XmlDocument on C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I was trying to write an automatic method that retrieve a value from an XML file.

as i wrote the following code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
```

I found out that when I'm trying to access `xDoc` object while typing `xDoc`. , it does nothing, means no option to manipulate the object...

my usings are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: re-start the Visual Studio.

Comment: What do you mean by "an automatic method"? It would help if you'd show a short but *complete* example - not just these snippets. For example, if you were trying to do this at the class declaration level, that could well be the problem. Does the code you've got (creating an instance) build?

Comment: @Selman22: already tried = not working.
plus, also I can't attached more code, because the next line will be manipulate the object who's not recognized as something...

Comment: Exactly where did you put that line of code. Please show us a full example, in a new file, of a class and method that has this problem. You may find that in a new class, you do not have the problem, that it only occurs in the specific place where you saw the problem.

Comment: Ok, you gave me a point of thinking LOL, I wrote the code on class root instead of main or any other method... what should I do now in order to finish this thread ? thx

Comment: It is in the System.Xml.Linq namespace, awol in your usings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make a class to put the XMLDocument in if (per your comment) that is the next line you could have attached.

What I mean is, as Jon Skeet said, are you sure Adam that you're not declaring the XMLDocument inside of the namespace instead of inside of a class.  Should be something like:

```
using System.Xml;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        XMLDocument xDoc = new XMLDocument();

        public void MyMethod() {
            xDoc.DocumentType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. In particular, you could have the answer, but I can't tell.

Comment: Inside a class it wont give you the option to manipulate an object for some reason.. only inside a method or a Main method...